# Creating and applying ml_lib pipeline with external parameter in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, sparklyr

I am trying to create and apply a `Spark` `ml_pipeline` object that can handle an external parameter that will vary (typically a date). According to the `Spark` documentation, it seems possible: see part with `ParamMap` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-pipeline.html#parameters)

I haven't tried exactly how to do it. I was thinking of something like this:

```
table.df <- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3))
table.sdf <- sdf_copy_to(sc, table.df)

param = 5
param2 = 4

# operation declaration
table2.sdf <- table.sdf %>% 
  mutate(test = param)

# pipeline creation
pipeline_1 = ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(table2.sdf) %>%
  ml_fit(table.sdf, list("param" = param))

# pipeline application with another value for param
table2.sdf <- pipeline_1 %>% 
  ml_transform(table.sdf, list("param" = param2))

#result

glimpse(table2.sdf %>% select(test))
# doesn work...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really not how Spark ML Pipelines are intended to be used. In general all transformations required to convert input dataset to a format that is suitable for the `Pipeline` should be applied beforehand and only the common components should be embedded as `stages`.

When using native (Scala) API, it is technically possible, in such simple cases, like this one, to use an empty `SQLTransformer`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamPair

val df = spark.range(1, 4).toDF("a")

val sqlTransformer = new SQLTransformer()
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(sqlTransformer))
```

and supply `statement` `Param` for both `fit`

```
val model = pipeline.fit(
  df,
  ParamPair(sqlTransformer.statement, "SELECT *, 4 AS `test` FROM __THIS__")
)

model.transform(df).show
```

```
+---+----+
|  a|test|
+---+----+
|  1|   4|
|  2|   4|
|  3|   4|
+---+----+
```

and `transform`:

```scala
model.transform(
  df,
  ParamPair(sqlTransformer.statement, "SELECT *, 5 AS `test` FROM __THIS__")
 ).show
```

```
+---+----+
|  a|test|
+---+----+
|  1|   5|
|  2|   5|
|  3|   5|
+---+----+
```

but neither [`ml_fit`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/f69ce129952220dbb8b1bc53a7c9f26a01c57636/R/ml_transformation_methods.R#L26-L33) nor [`ml_transform` / `ml_predict`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/f69ce129952220dbb8b1bc53a7c9f26a01c57636/R/ml_transformation_methods.R#L91-L93) supports additional `Params` at the moment (as you can see `...` are simply ignored).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The goal is to be able to apply these transformations with external parameters that may varry, like dates typically.