# Spark ML_pipelines: managing table reading

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using Spark `ML_pipelines` to easily deploy operations that I have developed in `Sparklyr` in a production environment using `SCALA`. It is working pretty well, except for one part: it seems that when I read a table from `Hive` and then create a pipeline that applies operations to this table the pipeline will also save the table reading operation and thereby the name of the table. However I want the pipeline to be independent of this.

Here is a reproducible example:

`Sparklyr` part:

```
sc = spark2_context(memory = "4G")

iris <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite=TRUE)

spark_write_table(iris, "base.iris")
spark_write_table(iris, "base.iris2")
df1 <- tbl(sc, "base.iris")

df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(foo = 5)

pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(df2) %>%
  ml_fit(df1)

ml_save(pipeline,
        paste0(save_pipeline_path, "test_pipeline_reading_from_table"),
        overwrite = TRUE)

df2 <- pipeline %>% ml_transform(df1)

dbSendQuery(sc, "drop table base.iris")
```

`SCALA`part:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val df1 = spark.sql("select * from base.iris2") 

val pipeline = PipelineModel.load(pipeline_path + "/test_pipeline_reading_from_table")
val df2 = pipeline.transform(df1)
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `base`.`iris`; line 2 pos 5;
'Project ['Sepal_Length, 'Sepal_Width, 'Petal_Length, 'Petal_Width, 'Species, 5.0 AS foo#110]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `base`.`iris`

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:637)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer.transformSchema(SQLTransformer.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transformSchema$5.apply(Pipeline.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transformSchema$5.apply(Pipeline.scala:310)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:310)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.transform(Pipeline.scala:304)
  ... 71 elided
```

I can see 2 solutions:

1. It seems that persisting `dataframe` would be a solution, but then I would need to find a way not to overload my memory, hence my question on [unpersisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342887/how-to-unpersist-in-sparklyr)
2. Passing the name of the table in Hive as a parameter of the pipeline, which I am trying to solve in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328900/creating-and-applying-ml-lib-pipeline-with-external-parameter-in-sparklyr)

Now, all of this being said, I might be missing something as I am only a beginner...

EDIT: this is significantly different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534224/how-to-train-a-ml-model-in-sparklyr-and-predict-new-values-on-another-dataframe) as this concerns the specific problem of integrating a dataframe that was just read in a pipeline, as specified in the title.

EDIT: as for my project, persisting the tables after I read them is a viable solution. I don't know if there is any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Then the pipeline would call my table "base.table", making it impossible to apply it to another table.

That's actually not true. `ft_dplyr_transformer` is a syntactic sugar for Spark's own `SQLTransformer`. Internally `dplyr` [expression is converted to SQL query, and the name of the table is replaced with `__THIS__`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/7ea167c944c7ec17537ef0f9cb076f53b54e052f/R/ml_feature_sql_transformer.R#L85) (Spark placeholder referring to the current table).

Let's say you have transformation like this one:

```r
copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite=TRUE)

df <- tbl(sc, "iris") %>%
  mutate(foo = 5)

pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(df) %>%
  ml_fit(tbl(sc, "iris"))

ml_stage(pipeline, "dplyr_transformer") %>% spark_jobj() %>% invoke("getStatement")
```

```
[1] "SELECT `Sepal_Length`, `Sepal_Width`, `Petal_Length`, `Petal_Width`, `Species`, 5.0 AS `foo`\nFROM `__THIS__`"
```

That's however rather confusing way expressing things, and it makes more sense to use native SQL transformer directly:

```
pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_sql_transformer("SELECT *, 5 as `foo` FROM __THIS__") %>%
  ml_fit(df)
```

**Edit**:

The problem you experience here looks like a bug. [`get_base_name`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/7ea167c944c7ec17537ef0f9cb076f53b54e052f/R/ml_feature_sql_transformer.R#L77-L82) function returns unquoted table name, so the value in your case will be

```
> get_base_name(x$ops)
<IDENT> default.iris
```

and the pattern will be

```
> pattern
[1] "\\bdefault.iris\\b"
```

However [`dbplyr::sql_render`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/7ea167c944c7ec17537ef0f9cb076f53b54e052f/R/ml_feature_sql_transformer.R#L85) returns backquoted fully qualified name:

```
> dbplyr::sql_render(x)
<SQL> SELECT `Sepal_Length`, `Sepal_Width`, `Petal_Length`, `Petal_Width`, `Species`, 5.0 AS `foo`
FROM `default`.`iris`
```

So the pattern doesn't match the name.